# How to check if a string contains each regex

Tags: ruby

I would like to check if a string includes all of the given regexs. I dont want to go through the string for each regex.

`return "foo".all_chars {include? ( \letter\ && \number\ && \special\)}`

or

`return "foo".all_chars {include? ( \letter , number , special\)}`

Comment: There is no method `String#all_chars` and `\letter\ && \number\ && \special\` is not a valid Ruby object. I do not understand the question. Please edit to correct and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> I dont want to go through the string for each regex.

You'd end up with a really nasty, unreadable, and unmaintainable regex pattern. But if you want to you could combine them, and then just call `match?` on it.

Given...

```
regex1 = %r{[a-z]}
regex2 = %r{[^aeiou]}

all_regex = %r{[a-z&&[^aeiou]]}
```

But here's really no harm in using `Enumerable#all?`

`[regex1, regex2, regex3].all? { |regex| string.match?(regex) }`

Comment: lol im not worried about maintainability... how do you put multiple regex in chunk

Comment: Eh. I doubt `%r{[a-z&&[^aeiou]]}` does what you expect it to do.